# How do I pass query string parameters on Drupal affiliate links?

Tags: nodes

I am using the drupal [affliate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/affiliate). I wanted to pass a query string along with the affiliate link the module provided, but every time a user visits the link the string gets ignored and redirects to the node without passing the string.

My link looks similar to www.example.com/aff/1/node|34?name=ibo. What I expected was the sting being passed along, and the node being www.example.com/node/34?name=ibo. The string is lost on redirection to the node, and I am only left with www.example.com/node/34.

Can you guys show me how I can achive this?